# Transaction not propagated or mined on Rinkeby

Tags: transactions, infura, rinkeby

I create ETH transactions programatically and send them to the Infura Rinkeby node as rawTransaction. The transaction in questios is accepted by the node, but can't be found by other nodes (Alchemyapi, Etherscan). If I submit the transaction to either of those other nodes they will be accepted there. Only a node where I manually submitted the transaction with `sendRawTransaction` is able to find the transaction via `getTransactionByHash`.

From this I'm concluding, that the transaction is not propagated through the network. `blockHash` and `blockNumber` will also stay `null`.

Is it possible to create a transaction that is considered valid by all the nodes, but won't be mined or propagated because it's broken in another way?

This is the raw transaction:

```
0xf86c81f5851414e68e8082520894cbff0f11f63773f69968782d9b91e97cfcb90b1f87442c11036f0c00802ba0d5d79b07f6927845f0481f5379c1f353d62bcb5597b07774ab324ccb815b73afa07262a3b7c0d9cc8f0145db85d1aa8e8eeac45d4f152497e9f8dc478f07292290
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was that the nonce was too high by 1. The nodes will accept the transaction, but won't broadcast them and will drop them after a while.